# Alternate nodes in a SQL Server XQuery path?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Is there any way to have a sort of "alternates group" like in Regular Expressions, in an XQuery path in SQL Server?

I have this query...

```
SELECT Q.ROWID QUEUEID, Q.DOCUMENTPACKAGETYPE, 
    B.R.value('@_ID', 'NAME') PARTYID,
    B.R.value('@_BorrowerID', 'NAME') BORROWERID,
    B.R.value('@_Name', 'NAME') NAME,
    B.R.value('@_EmailAddress', 'NAME') EMAILADDRESS
FROM docutech.QUEUE_EX Q 
CROSS APPLY Q.DATA.nodes('LOAN_PUSHBACK_PACKAGE/EVENT_DATA/ESIGN/PARTY') AS B(R)
WHERE Q.REASONFORPUSHBACK = 'DocumentDistribution' AND B.R.value('@_Type', 'NAME') = 'Borrower'
```

But what I need, is for the `CROSS APPLY` the ESIGN node in the path can actually be either ESIGN or ECLOSE. So I am looking to do something like the following (thinking in RegEx terms)...

```
CROSS APPLY Q.DATA.nodes('LOAN_PUSHBACK_PACKAGE/EVENT_DATA/(ESIGN)|(ECLOSE)/PARTY') AS B(R)
```

Is there any way to do something like this? I'd really hate to have to repeat the same query twice, just for that simple difference, though maybe `XQuery` doesn't support options like that?

Actually, I just found I **can** use an asterisk, which will match both, but I'd LIKE to be able to limit it to those known node values if possible. If not, I guess that will do.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it what you need. Here is conceptual example for you.

The XPath predicate expression is checking that the element names at a particular level belong to a sequence of specified names. The `<SomethingElse>` element is not a member of the sequence, that's why its data is not retrieved.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<LOAN_PUSHBACK_PACKAGE>
    <EVENT_DATA>
        <ESIGN>
            <PARTY _Name="one"/>
        </ESIGN>
        <ECLOSE>
            <PARTY _Name="two"/>
        </ECLOSE>
        <SomethingElse>
            <PARTY _Name="three"/>
        </SomethingElse>
    </EVENT_DATA>
</LOAN_PUSHBACK_PACKAGE>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('@_Name','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Name] 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/LOAN_PUSHBACK_PACKAGE/EVENT_DATA/*[local-name(.)=("ESIGN","ECLOSE")]/PARTY') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------+
| Name |
+------+
| one  |
| two  |
+------+
```

Comment: That did it! And bonus, it dropped out a few rows from the `*` that exposed other record types we're getting back from the 3rd party data source. (They provide very little in the way of documentation!) ... What is this syntax referred to in the XQuery world? I had tried googling `reg ex`, `options`, `alternates`, `optional groups`, and a few others and couldn't figure this out. Knowing the right names in the land of XQuery might help figure out any further questions I may come up with.

Comment: Heh... figured out how to determine what it matched on too, by adding the following field to my `SELECT` fields list:
`B.R.value('local-name(..)', 'NAME') PARENT`, which returns either **ESIGN** or **ECLOSE**.

Comment: @eidylon, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. **"...What is this syntax referred to in the XQuery world?.."** It is a sequence in XQuery parlance. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.